# Canonical embedding into dual space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How would one go about proving that there is no embedding of a vector space into it's dual that is independent of a choice of basis? Thanks

Comment: One should start by stating a formal interpretation of this informal claim. (Full disclosure: I don't know how this is done. "Independent of a choice of basis" is a vague notion that isn't straightforwardly formalizable.)

Comment: What if it is an inner product space?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I believe the proper formalization involves natural transformations; in this sense, this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Example:_dual_of_a_finite-dimensional_vector_space) is relevant.

Comment: @Hayden Interesting that a question on vector spaces and their duals would involve category theory.

Comment: @user_of_math It's not the linear algebra that makes it come up, it's the thought of "independent of basis".  This can be essentially rephrased as "without making arbitrary choices", and this is precisely what natural transformations try to capture; the commutative square that natural transformations necessarily fulfill essentially tells one how to transform between these "choices" in an unambiguous way.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists such linear isomorphism and name it Q , so $Q(b_n)=b^n$ and $$(Q(b_n))(b_m)=(b^n)(b_m)=\delta_{mn}$$
now assume other basis like $$b_{11}=b_1 ,\ \ b_{22}=b_1+b_2\ \ , b_{33}=b_1+b_2+b_3 ,\ \ .... \ \ , b_{nn}=b_1+b_2+b_3+...+b_n $$
now we have $$Q(b_{nn})=Q(b_1)+Q(b_2)+...+Q(b_n)$$
and we must have $(Q(b_{nn}))(b_{mm})=\delta_{mn}$

now if 
$m \ne n$ $$(Q(b_{nn}))(b_{mm})=(Q(b_{nn}))(b_{m})=(Q(b_1)+Q(b_2)+...+Q(b_n))(b_{m})=(\delta_{1m}+\delta_{2n}+\delta_{3n}+...+\delta_{nm})=1$$
which contradicts with $$(Q(b_{nn}))(b_{mm})=0$$ .